# Core Data error on ManagedObjectContext Save

Tags: objective-c, core-data, ios5

Oof... having an issue here..

I'm using CoreData and the root view of my navigation controller gives a list of staff.

If I click a staff member, I push the detail view of that staff member.

If I click on one of the detail fields (i.e. 'Name' or 'Location') I push an editing view controller where I can change the data and then save.

I have two different edit controllers...  one for simple text edits ("EditTextController") and one for Location ("EditLocationController") which is a relationship field where you can select the location from a list.

If I create a new staff member, everything works perfectly.   I'm even able to update any of the text fields or location field without error.

The problem comes when I try to UPDATE an existing staff member.   I'm able to change their Location  no problem... no errors.   But if I try and update the textfield of an existing staff member I get a nasty error.

```
-[StaffListMasterViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to     instance 0x6d7e650
2012-02-21 14:32:14.663 FanOut[2664:fb03] CoreData: error: Serious application error.      
Exception was caught during Core Data change processing.  This is usually a bug within an 
observer of NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  -    
[StaffListMasterViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to  
instance 0x6d7e650 with userInfo (null)
2012-02-21 14:32:14.665 FanOut[2664:fb03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[StaffListMasterViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6d7e650'
```

It's confusing because the code in the two controllers seems to be identical

```
- (void) saveButtonPressed:(id) sender {

[managedObject setValue:textField.text forKey:keyString];

//Save the context
NSError *error = nil;
if (![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
} else {
     [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
}
```

I don't know.. I'm certain I probably have not provided enough information to figure this out.  But maybe if anyone has suggestions on what else I need to include for troubleshooting?   Thanks in advance...

Comment: Show the code for this method: -[StaffListMasterViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]. Update your question with this information, so you can get the benefit of text formatting.

Comment: Hey Jim,  that was it!  I commented out that method... can't even remember why.  Thank you so much.   Can you post your comment as an answer so I can accept it? Thanks

Comment: I go blind myself after several continuous hours looking at these things. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show the code for this method: -[StaffListMasterViewController configureCell:atIndexPath:]. Update your question with this information, so you can get the benefit of text formatting.